# Using REGEXP_MATCH, cannot categorize data with text string

Tags: looker

In Looker Studio, I'm using REGEXP_MATCH() to categorize a column of data from an NPS survey into Promoters, Passives, and Detractors. The options are as follows: "0 (not at all likely)", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", or "10 (extremely likely)". I have no problems correctly categorizing the purely numerical values into my desired categories, however my 0 and 10 values with affiliated text are not getting picked up by the REGEXP_MATCH() expression. I have tried many variations (below) and none of them are working correctly.

REGEXP_MATCH(How likely would you be to recommend this offering to others?, r'extremely likely')
...r'^[0-9]+\s*(extremely likely)$'
...r'^10\s*(extremely likely)$|^9$'
...r'^10\s*(extremely likely)$|9'
...r'^9|10 (extremely likely)$'
...r'^(9|10 (extremely likely))$'
...“(9|.*10.*)”
..."(9|.*extremely likely.*)"
I have tried all of these, among others. Every one of these options will correctly categorize the "9" as a promoter, but none of the "10 (extremely likely)" responses. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the parentheses around the `extremely likely` string, otherwise it gets understood as a capturing group. See the [doc of the re2 library](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax#:%7E:text=possessive%20(NOT%20SUPPORTED)-,Grouping,-(re)).
As a consequence something like `r'9|(10 \(extremely likely\))'` should be working fine.
I recommend experimenting on RegExps using https://regex101.com/ which is pretty easy to use and explains what your current RegExp is looking for.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks! I just tried your suggestion and it's still not picking up... I am starting to think there's something off about the formatting of my source data. Thank you for the input! I'll check out the Regex101 page for help!

Comment: Have you tried removing the aw string literal prefix, 'r' from your regexp and using `'9|(10 \(extremely likely\))'` instead of `r'9|(10 \(extremely likely\))'`. As per the [https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/10496674?sjid=14271544305783931910-EU&hl=en](documentation) it may lead backslashes to be interpreted literally.

Answer (score 0):

I can see there's a space after 0 and 10. Maybe you can get 2 leftmost characters, then convert to integer. That will be easier to do.
`CAST(LEFT(your_column,2) AS INT64)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. My raw data enters my spreadsheet via an integration, so there was an issue with the cell formatting. Once I copied the raw data over to another tab, the above solution worked perfectly!